# Is there a word for someone who tends to find faults in others?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

I'm looking for a single word, for someone who...

- keeps seeing everything that is wrong with everybody else.
- never seems to see the good of other people, only the bad things.
- points at others, as if he forgets he has weaknesses himself.
- does not brag about himself, he just seems to be dissatisfied with everyone else.

I prefer a word that is as unambiguous and clear-cut as possible.

Comment: Faulfinding :  disposed to find fault :  captiously critical. (M-W). I think you are  referring to too many things for just one word.

Comment: @Josh - I was about to mention the same thing :^) Many dictionaries list the adjective [fault-finding](http://www.onelook.com/?w=fault-finding&ls=a) and the noun [fault-finder](http://www.onelook.com/?w=fault-finder&ls=a).

Comment: The word you are looking for is Dota player (or me).

Comment: Surely, a realist :)

Comment: "Mother" springs to mind. Or "girlfriend"

Comment: Two words? [Negative Nancy, Debbie Downer, Pessimistic Patty](https://greeneggsandlam.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/three-people-i-cant-stand-debbie-downer-negative-nancy-and-pessimistic-patty/)? `Stop being such a negative nancy`

Comment: If you broaden the question to include *anything*, not just others, and there's no emotion involved, you could use the term `analytical`.  This is actually a bonus in some fields like software and other systems development.  It helps you find a majority of flaws prior to beginning an actual implementation.

Comment: @Mawg You forgot about "Wife"!

Comment: the word is "negative"

Comment: Mawg and Bookeater: I have some good news for you. Not all women are like that. Even better, about the same ratio of men are like that, too. This means there's no reason to be sexist. Isn't that great? And the best news of all; this means you don't have to date someone you don't actually get along with! Happy days! :D

Comment: The answer to the title is "almost everyone".

Comment: According to the character King Gama in Gilbert & Sullivan's *Princess Ida*, the word you are looking for is *philanthropist*.

Answer (score 20):

I just *cannot* resist mentioning the term ***[nitpicker](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/nitpicker)*** here.

> a person given to harsh judgments and to finding faults
>
> "a tiresome nitpicker who seems to think that I can't do anything right"

reference
http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/nitpicker

Answer (score 16):

- Captious.

1 : marked by an often ill-natured inclination to stress faults and raise objections

http://i.word.com/idictionary/captious

Comment: Bingo! That fits the ask *and* is a totally new word on me, so bonus points for feeding my lexophilia.

Comment: Thanks! It pays off to subscribe to word a day email lists.  And "captious" is easy to remember, as it sounds like "capture", as in GOTCHA.

Answer (score 12):

Such a person could be called '[Judgemental](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/judgemental)'

> **Judgemental**: Having or displaying an overly critical point of view

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like fault-finder, there's the verb *carp*:

> **[carp](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/carp)** (*v.*) to complain or find fault; nag pettily

The noun form is *carper*, but that's not a very common word.

Answer (score 2):

> keeps seeing everything that is wrong with everybody else.

That person is overly [critical](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+critical): expressing adverse or disapproving comments or judgments.

> never seems to see the good of other people, only the bad things.

That person is [pessimistic](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+pessimistic): tending to see the worst aspect of things or believe that the worst will happen.

> points at others, as if he forgets he has weaknesses himself.

That person is [hypocritical](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+hypocritical): behaving in a way that suggests one has higher standards or more noble beliefs than is the case.

> does not brag about himself, he just seems to be dissatisfied with everyone else.

That person is [cantankerous](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+cantankerous): bad-tempered, argumentative, and uncooperative.

Answer (score 0):

Failing to fight off the urge to say 'Journalist' I'll move swiftly on to a personal favorite: Jeremiah. It's a term that is falling out of use and I think that's a shame because it fits the needs of this question so well. Here's the entry from the OED (with a few of the examples):

> ...used allusively to denote a person given to lamentation or woeful complaining.
>
> 1905   Daily Chron. 1 Sept. 5/7   The Jeremiahs have been on the rampage; the dismal and the doleful would-be experts [etc.].
>
> 1928   Daily Express 23 Feb. 3/5   There are always Jeremiahs who go about saying that we have never had such bad times.
>
> 1963   Times 22 Apr. 8/5   Mr. Selwyn Lloyd..wanted to see Young Conservatives ‘rise up in protest against the Jeremiahs, defeatists, pessimists, denigrators’, [etc.].

Another unusual word that may be consideration is vituperator, from the verb vituperate - OED again:

> To blame, speak ill of, find fault with, in strong or violent language; to assail with abuse; to rate or revile.

Answer (score -1):

As I haven't seen it mentioned: the classic proto-Germanic rooted 'nag' (noun). Fits the bill perfectly in my mind.

Comment: What is in your mind that explains why it fits?

Answer (score -2):

Suitable word should be 'Cynical' according to your requirement.

You can also say 'Dissenting' , 'Antipathetic'.

Comment: Why does it fit? Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation.

Answer (score -2):

narcissist.  Yes, I read the fourth requirement, but in my estimation, this still seems to be the best description that I can give.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Mike. Perhaps you could point us to someone who can corroborate your estimate?

Answer (score -3):

If you're a [Harry Potter fan](https://www.google.com/search?q=quibbler&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=899&tbm=isch&imgil=Fe5v9b3hoB5m5M%253A%253Bji9amHIrm148wM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fharrypotter.wikia.com%25252Fwiki%25252FThe_Quibbler&source=iu&pf=m&fir=Fe5v9b3hoB5m5M%253A%252Cji9amHIrm148wM%252C_&usg=__Ep7naGnDs-EPr1gQi0P1JJ5at90%3D&ved=0CCoQyjc&ei=ZmySVafNK9iLuATIzIrICg#imgrc=Fe5v9b3hoB5m5M%3A&usg=__Ep7naGnDs-EPr1gQi0P1JJ5at90%3D), or your audience is, you can go with '**[quibbler](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quibble)**'

> **Quibble**: n.  petty or carping criticism;
>
> v. to carp; cavil.

Comment: I doubt that seeing the faults that others make is a "trivial matter".

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: The trivial matter is not seeing faults. Quibblers see faults _about_ trivial matters. Use your head.

Comment: Basically: the faults aren't trivial matters, the faults are *the* trivial matter? And I assure you that I'm using my head.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: If you're quibbling, you're finding faults in trivial matters. Doesn't mean what you're doing (quibbling) is trivial. Please see links for examples and better explanation.

Comment: The link explains less than expected. And I read it twice. And after reading your comment, I can see that the word doesn't seem to fit. I really can't see how finding faults in people relates to findind faults in trivial matters.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: (A) The issue at hand isn't whether the def fits. It's that your first comment still doesn't make any sense as it's based on a faulty understanding of the definition. (B) Quibbling or carping means criticizing every small thing _someone_ does.

Comment: So, you are a quibbler?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: So, you've graduated to being wise from being wrong?

Comment: I have no idea what you meant, but it's better if we stop here.