# Adjective or noun for a person who takes offence deliberately or insincerely

Tags: adjectives

I'm looking an adjective that means someone is deliberately finding fault and playing up being offended.

*Alice is...* Quarrelsome? Captious? Fault-finding?

Comment: Get better friends.

Comment: In football this is called flopping, and in basketball it's called working the refs. In social situations, not sure. There is surely a word.

Comment: Well, there's "touchy".

Comment: Your example is about someone determined to find fault not take offence. In which case this is a duplicate http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255949/is-there-a-word-for-someone-who-tends-to-find-faults-in-others

Comment: So why did you submit a self answer with "Captious" then? That doesn't indicate anything about a specific individual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several words like quarrelsome, argumentative & confrontational (may be more) but the closest I can find to your (example) scenario is ***antagonistic***. (See the example from ODO below which is pretty close to yours).

ODO:

> **[antagonistic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/antagonistic)**
>
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Showing or feeling **active opposition or hostility towards someone** or something:
>
> ‘He was rude and antagonistic to my friends, kept picking arguments
>   and was often deliberately provocative, manipulating people into tense
>   arguments.’

Comment: Antagonistic fits the bill very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

*Alice is a stirrer*.

(Aka a shit stirrer or pot stirrer.)

Perhaps this is too general since it is not limited to the *incincere offense-seeking*

> **Stirrer**
>
> British informal. A person who deliberately causes trouble between others by spreading rumours or gossip.
> [...].
> *‘Unlike Walter, he is a stirrer, a deliberately provocative commentator and a freewheeling iconoclast, infamous for his relentless critique of the American government and military.’*
> [OD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stirrer)

Answer (score 2):

You might say Alice is *captious*:

> Tending to find fault or raise petty objections:
>   ‘a captious teacher’

From [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/captious).

Answer (score 2):

Although not directly related to taking offense, the two words that immediately came to mind were

> [**Argumentative**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/argumentative)
>
> adjective  ​
>
> often arguing or wanting to argue:

and...

> **[Contrarian](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/contrarian)**
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> Opposing or rejecting popular opinion or current practice:

Contrarian fits less, but it summons an image of someone who *wants to* or is *looking for an excuse to* disagree with someone for one reason or another.

Alice is being intentionally **arguementative** or **contrarian** as a means of expressing her dislike of Bob.